# Does there exist a set of all cardinals?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

Does there exist set that contains all the cardinal numbers?

Comment: This has been asked several times before. Once recently.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assume $C$ was the set of all cardinals. Then $\bigcup C$ would be a cardinal exceeding all cardinals in $C$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: While true this argument presupposes knowledge in cardinal and ordinal arithmetics. I have a hard time seeing how someone familiar with ordinals will not see the answer to this question immediately.

Comment: @AsafKaragila When one is learning something for the first time "obvious" things aren't usually so obvious.

Comment: This would also imply that there is no function that maps n to $\aleph_n$?

Comment: @PyRulez The cardinals are not limited to the $\aleph_n$'s, they go way way beyond that.

Comment: Wait, how is that from n to $ \aleph_n$? $f(3) \neq \aleph_3$!

Comment: How is that a map from $\omega$ to the $\aleph$'s?

Comment: @PyRulez: The set $\{\aleph_n\mid n\in\omega\}$ is not the set of all cardinals. The map $n\mapsto\aleph_n$ is injective and well-defined. But $\aleph_\omega$ is a cardinality above all the $\aleph_n$'s.

Comment: What is above that?

Comment: @PyRulez $\aleph_{\omega + 1}$ for example...

Comment: @PyRulez Sorry, I misread what you wrote above: I don't see how this implies that the map $n \mapsto \aleph_n$ is not injective (assuming that's what you meant, but maybe I still don't understand you).

Comment: @Matt: I think the question was whether or not the map is even defined (the image of a set is a set, if $\omega$ is a set but $\{\aleph_n\mid n\in\omega\}$ is not then the function is not well-defined.

Answer (score 0):

Set of cardinals is well ordered by $\in$. Now, as a corollary we get  Burali-Forti theorem, which says that there is no the set of all ordinal numbers.
As a corollary from a corollary we can prove that, there is no set that contains all the ordinals.
Proof: Let $A$ be a set that contains all the ordinals. You can prove that $\{x\in A : x \ \text{is ordinal}\}$ is a set, which contradicts Burali-Forti theorem.